# implementing html tags of js variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript, kendo-ui

- When I click open first window link a popup opens.
- in that popup you will see a grid with two columns.
- in that first column i need to combine name and and icon.
- so i added span tag before a tag but its not working.
- can you guys tell me how to combine.
- providing code below.

http://jsfiddle.net/cepzsokp/

```
var a = $('<span></span><a/>', {
          class: 'sportsDataPlayer',
          download: 'download.csv',
          type: 'text/csv',
          href: URL.createObjectURL(data),
          html: ev.FileName
        });
        return a[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: Makes no sense adding the span in there.....

Comment: @epascarello hey thanks for your reply.... I need to show the image...I am trying to combine this return value------> return "<span onclick=\"window.open('" + model.mobileVersion + "', 'popup', 'width=800,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no')\  with this one ------> return a[0].outerHTML;

Comment: you would need to append the span and anchor to an element or just do `return "<span></span>" + a[0].outerHTML;`

Comment: @epascarello can you update in my code...I tried so many ways but I am not successful :(

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that html mark up. easiest thing would be just add the span before the outerHTML

```
var a = $('<a></a>', {...})
return "<span></span>" + a[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: hey with normal span tag its working...but with span tag its breaking any idea....providing fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/6aa15duj/   ---------->   return "<span onclick=\"window.open('" + model.mobileVersion + "', 'popup', 'width=800,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no')\" class='" + skyCloudmageProfilePic + " displayInlineBlock " + kendotxtMenu + "'>
  </span>" + a[0].outerHTML;

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your latest jsfiddle. Here is the working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/6aa15duj/2/)

I have modified this line of code as below:

```
return "<span onclick=&quot;window.open('" + model.mobileVersion + "', 'popup', 'width=800,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no')&quot; class='" + skyCloudmageProfilePic + " displayInlineBlock " + kendotxtMenu + "'></span>" + a[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: Hey can you let me know what you did so that in future I can do it by myself

Comment: You had bad double quotes which was breaking the things, so I converted that to &quot; which is a safe way to quote the strings and values when a lot of single and double quotes are involved.

Comment: You can consider accepting my answer if my code has helped you :)